# ScrollView does not fill the hole parent view

Tags: android, scrollview

I'm working with a `ListView` and on the `OnClickListener` method and I start a new `Activity` with the info of the item that has been selected from the list.

In the new `Activity` (`InfoActivity`) I have a `ScrollView` that has a background color. I set the `android:fillViewPort = "true"` but the view has a blank at the margin of the `ScrollView`. I can't make it dissapear.

**InfoActivity Fragment layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="#9999"
        tools:context=".ClienteInfoActivity">


<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_with_shadow"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Informacion"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_nombre"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cliente_info_nombre_label"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_apellido_pat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_nombre"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:text="@string/cliente_info_apellido_pat_label"

            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_apellido_mat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_apellido_pat"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_apellido_pat"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/cliente_info_apellido_mat_label"/>




    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rl_info"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_with_shadow"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

        >

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tv_telefono_info"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:text="@string/cliente_info_telefono_label"

        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_telefono"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_telefono_info"
            android:text="@string/cliente_info_telefono_label"
            android:textSize="18dp"

            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib_call"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_telefono"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_call"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

            />
        <!--<View-->
            <!--android:layout_width="1dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="30dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ib_call"-->
            <!--android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ib_call"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginRight="10dp"-->
            <!--android:background="@color/primary_dark_material_dark" />-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_email_info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/cliente_info_email_label"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_telefono"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_email_info"
            android:text="@string/cliente_info_email_label"

            />
         <ImageButton
             android:id="@+id/ib_send_email"
             android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
             android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
             android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_email"
             android:background="@drawable/ic_send_email"
          />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_telefono"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@color/primary_dark_material_dark" />

     </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>




</ScrollView>
```

Below is what I get

[image]

Edit:
The main_activity layout had a margin, and the container was set to this layout, anyway i deleted the margins from the main_activity layout and the ScrollView filled the parent.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to add orientation attribute in scrollview. By default orientatipn is horizontal.

Comment: @Simar ScrollView does not have orientation attribute, does it?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what your incorrect view looks like?

Comment: It does. //This ans is too short.

Comment: @pasta12 I have the screenshot ready but the site wont let me upload it, because i need 10 points of reputation before i can upload images.

Comment: @Simar Certainly not in Android.

Comment: @FabianLoayza you can post a link to it and a higher rep user can add the image

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/PiFSD.jpg here is the link the site gave me. as you can see there is some kind of blank margin around the ScrollView and i want it to dessapear

Comment: @codeMagic I just tried your advice it did not work for me. thanks anyway

Comment: You have margins and paddings set to you `RelativeLayout`s - does it surprise you that they HAVE margins and paddings?

Comment: @Nuwisam i have paddings and margins on the RelativeLayout s for the ScrollView, those margins apply only inside the content of the ScrollView.

Comment: @FabianLoayza You must have another view or the activity's root view setting padding that's affecting the scrollview. I don't see this being a problem with the scrollview itself. More likely the parent affecting it.

Comment: this is your fragment layout right? can you check your activity layout whether you have any margin set?

Comment: @pasta12 and Dara Thank you both of you, your answers gave me the solution! The main_activity layout had a margin, and the container was set to this layout, anyway i deleted the margins from the main_activity layout and the ScrollView filled the parent.

Comment: @FabianLoayza instead of editing the solution into the OP, you should post an answer instead. If you are unsure about giving credit where due and whatnot, [see this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments). Many good answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your activity has padding. Check your activity xml for padding on the parent of the fragment's container...

Comment: Yes it was that, i edited the question with the solution. Thanks